# How should I set up a repo to store private github actions for my org

Tags: typescript, github, github-actions

I want to have multiple typescript actions in a private repo to reuse across my org. The the folder structure looks like this:

```
.github/
  workflows/
    ...
actions/
  action-1/
    action.yml
    index.ts
    ...
  action-2/
    action.yml
    index.ts
    ...
```

I want to be able to reference the actions by branch name rather than versions. So I can reference `org/actions-repo/action1@main`.

My questions are:

1. do I need to compile the typescript or can github do this when it uses the actions.
2. if I do need to compile it as if I am creating a proper release, where should the compiled the js be stored?

Comment: The recommendation is to put every action in its own repo, instead of a single repo with may actions in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your action needs to be setup (in its folder) the same way any GitHub action is setup.  This means that 1) it needs to be compiled and 2) this is stored in the repo (typically a `dist` folder however you can specify the entry point to be anything).

You can reference the first part [actions/typescript-action](https://github.com/actions/typescript-action) to see how they have it setup. This repo, with the exception of things like the .github folder, is what each of your actions folders should look like.

Comment: So in my action.yml files, the main field should point to dist/action-name/index.js?

Comment: Yes, you need to point to the compiled js file that's committed in the repo. You could have a GitHub actions workflow that compiles the JS and pushes them to the branch... But there is no build-in feature.